# Selecting different div with attribute on css

Tags: html, css

What I want to happen is to change the login page only and i'm doing this with 'CUSTOM CSS' block only.

Code I've tested work change the login background yet it mess up to other pages:

```
#root > span:nth-child(1) > div[style]{
background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58), rgba(255, 86, 0, 0.81) ), /*Filter*/
url(https://i.imgur.com/mv3mI8T.png) !important;/*Background image of login, DO NOT ADD !IMPORTANT*/
padding-bottom: 30% ;/*Space below the content*/
}
```

**Output Login Page | Status: Works Fine**

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(242, 244, 249);">
```

[image]

**Output Order Page | Status: Mess-up**

```
<div class="bg-white height-100" style="position: absolute; top: 4rem; width: 100%;">
```

[image]

I've also tried this just incase this is possible not to select with atribute of style to style and output of this is only white, because it loads the bg-white class:

```
#root > span:nth-child(1) > div[style="background-color: rgb(242, 244, 249);"]:not[style="position: absolute; top: 4rem; width: 100%;"] {
background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58), rgba(255, 86, 0, 0.81) ), /*Filter*/
url(https://i.imgur.com/mv3mI8T.png) !important; 
padding-bottom: 30% ;
}
```

I guess it doesn't do what i want to do..

To professional at CSS, can you guys help me on how to select this correctly ?

Comment: I don't have access to HTML by the way

Answer (score 0):

I Finally fixed it, i used :not() then select the class that should not be affected.

```
#root > span:nth-child(1) > div[style]:not(.bg-white):not(.view-delivery-order):not(.auth-error)
```